# How can I execute app on remote desktop with a batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, exe, remote-desktop

Is there any way to start a cmd on a remote computer, and then start exe file with a path to it, even if some user is logged on the remote machine.
I have restricted admin rights, and I can not use psexec.
the job should be done with a batch and show the cmd window to the user logged on, so they know something is happening, because some services will bi stopped for 1h.
I tried this:

```
WMIC /NODE:"name remote comp" /user user /password password process call create "c:\dir1\dir2\dir3\some.exe" /M /NOREBOOT
```

and some other variations, nothing is happening.

Thanks in advance

I have the permission to run the exe file. I start it logged on the remote machine. I just need to automate the process in the case it should start on view computers at the same time. So I dont need to login and start it on each machine. I tried this also:

```
WMIC /NODE:"name remote comp" /user user /password password process call create "cmd.exe c:\dir1\dir2\dir3\some.exe" /M /NOREBOOT

WMIC /NODE:"name remote comp" /user user /password password process call create "cmd.exe /c c:\dir1\dir2\dir3\some.exe" /M /NOREBOOT

WMIC /NODE:"name remote comp" /user user /password password process call create "cmd.exe /c c:\dir1\dir2\dir3\some.exe /M /NOREBOOT"
```

Comment: Given that you've said that you have restricted admin rights, are you sure you'll have the required permissions? I ask because, in my experience, executable files with the `/NoReboot` option are generally installing something into system protected locations, or modifying existing system protected files. I addition to that, if you're wanting to run it in a cmd window, your command will need to be `cmd.exe` and the rest would be its arguments.

Comment: You could do yourself a favor and prepare for the future by setting up PowerShell Remoting and use `Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'otherhost'...`

Comment: I started to learn ps, but I never used it before, so it will take some time.

Comment: @bossbug, did you consider trying it using the advice I gave you about your provided command after you provided it in both the comment area, and then the now deleted answer? I ask because you've added it to your question, without those modifications. And just because nobody ever provides real information, if your executable file is using Windows Installer, you may be able to use `…product call install…` instead.

Comment: yes I tried with the /c switch after cmd.exe, but nothing happens on the remote pc. In my case, the bat needs to start a exe file to build a backup image.